# why does protractor return rgba instead of rgb?

Tags: css, angularjs, protractor

so I would like to get the color of an element in rgb format, mainly because the original code is written that way. But when doing the following protractor returns the color as rgba rather than rgb for background color.

`Tile.minorQuadrant.getCssValue("background-color");`

I also noticed that using 'fill' instead of 'background-color' does return rgb. do we know why protractor does this? The reason for asking is because I would like to have some consistency with the two values.

Comment: Probably because the simulated browser supports alpha values so it's saves cssValues as rgba. Then when you use getCssValue it returns that saved value.

Comment: Fill didn't used to support rgba as I recall and has a separate property `fill-opacity` as well.

Comment: @BobBrinks I'm using the latest version of firefox and chrome. At this stage I assume they both support rgba and it could be that they are both just doing what you say